# Create Cypher query: mixing default and dynamic properties

Tags: neo4j

I was wondering if this was possible to do

```
query: CREATE_NODE = 'CREATE (n:{label} {nodeId: {nodeId}, name:{name}, {props} }) RETURN n',
params:{
  'label': 'thing-label',
  'nodeId': 'thing-id',
  'name': 'thing-name',
  'props':{
    'addProps1':'addProp1',
    'addProps2:'addProp2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use labels as parameters since they might result in a different internal query plan. So to have different labels you need to build up the cypher string dynamically on client side.

Passing in a map as parameter for all properties is possible, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-parameters.html#_setting_all_properties_on_node. Mixing this with specific properties will most likely not work (haven't checked myself).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! :)
Then, is it possible to combine and Create and Set on the same query?
I basically want to have some properties to be the same through out all different types of nodes but have other unique properties added if necessary so I was thinking I can CREATE with the default parameters and add additional properties using SET:n {props}.. or something along the lines. Does that make sense??

Comment: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-set.html
states that I can use the '+=' operator but it is telling me I have a syntax error :(

Comment: the "+=" option is part of Neo4j 2.1 which is currently on milestone label. To achieve the same on 2.0, you might use `MERGE` together with `ON CREATE`.

Comment: regarding the failing `+=` operator please feel free to file a github issue at http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues